# Python - Plotting and linear regression - x and y must be the same size

Tags: python, plot, scikit-learn, linear-regression, prediction

I'm teaching myself some more tricks with python and scikit, and I'm trying to plot a linear regression model. My code can be seen below. But my program and console give the following error: `x and y must be the same size`. Additionally, my program makes it to the end of my code, but nothing gets plotted.

To fix the size error, the first thing that came to mind was testing the length of x and y with something like `len(x) == len(y)`. But as far as I can tell, my data seems to be the same length. Maybe the error is referring to something other than length (if so, I'm not sure what). Would really appreciate any help.

[image]

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import linear_model
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create linear regression object
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

#load csv file with pandas
df = pd.read_csv("pokemon.csv")
#remove all string columns
df = df.drop(['Name','Type_1','Type_2','isLegendary','Color','Pr_Male','hasGender','Egg_Group_1','Egg_Group_2','hasMegaEvolution','Body_Style'], axis=1)

y= df.Catch_Rate

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(df, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)

# Train the model using the training sets
regr.fit(x_train, y_train)

# Make predictions using the testing set
pokemon_y_pred = regr.predict(x_test)

print (pokemon_y_pred)

# Plot outputs
plt.title("Linear Regression Model of Catch Rate")
plt.scatter(x_test, y_test,  color='black')
plt.plot(x_test, pokemon_y_pred, color='blue', linewidth=3)

plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())

plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the lengths of `x` and `y` with `print(len(x))` and `print(len(y))`? Simply writing `len(x) == len(y)` in your code won't do anything (perhaps you were thinking of `assert len(x) == len(y)`, which will raise an AssertionError if x and y aren't the same length).

Comment: What exactly is `cross_validation.train_test_split`??

Comment: @Joel I should have been more specific -- I did print the lengths, I was just chalking my test up to seeing if the two sets were equal. Would it have anything to do with 1D vs 2D arrays?

Comment: @GarrettMcClure most likely. Are `x` and `y` of different dimensions?

Comment: @desertnaut http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html

Comment: @GarrettMcClure I know of course `model_selection.train_test_split`, but not `cross_validation.train_test_split` - until of course now: http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html - still, the term is a surprize...

Comment: It looks like you are passing the full dataframe `df` as the first argument to `train_test_split`. The first argument should be only the `x` (independent variable) part of the `df`.

Comment: @enumaris I think I understand. So instead of passing the entire dataframe `df`, I should compare it and make my predictions with an `x` part of `df`. For example, maybe I should choose a part of the dataset, such as the `total` column as my x variable and use that instead?

Comment: @GarrettMcClure If you are doing a single variable regression, that means you have a variable `x` which is an independent variable upon which you want to predict some other variable `y`. What you choose as your `x` variable is something you have to choose yourself - not something scikit-learn will automatically choose for you. If you are doing a multi-linear regression then `x` becomes a set of variables, but again you have to choose those yourself. You should not pass your entire dataset including `y` to the first argument of `train_test_split`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is referring to the fact that your x-variable has more than one dimension; plot and scatter only work for 2D plots, and it seems that your `x_test` has multiple features while `y_test` and `pokemon_y_pred` are one-dimensional.

Comment: I see. So I should convert my `pokemon_y_pred` into a 2D array?

Comment: No, the x and y variables must be both one-dimensional for plot or scatter to work. It depends on what exactly you are trying to visualize. You can plot ````pokemon_y_pred```` against one feature (column) from ````x_test```` perfectly fine. You could also plot two features from ````x_test```` on the x- and y-axes and color the points using ````pokemon_y_pred````'s values, for example.

Answer (score 0):

This error generates only when you have more different values of x for one y actually there are comparatively more columns in x_test than y_test.Thats why there is a size problem.
There should not be different x for one y:-basic mathematics fundamental.